# Mysql get last data by date

Tags: mysql

table inventorys

```
stock id cost       date   id   Type
ABC     1000.00 2018-01-01  1   BEGINING_QTY
ABC     2000.00 2018-02-01  2   PURCHASE
ABC     3000.00 2018-02-03  3   PURCHASE
BBB     1000.00 2018-01-01  4   BEGINING_QTY
BBB    20000.00 2018-10-01  5   PURCHASE
BBB    3000.00  2018-10-05  6   PURCHASE
```

i will get data like this

```
stock_id   cost     date
ABC        3000      2018-02-03
BBB        3000      2018-10-05
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful.

```
SELECT inventorys.stock_id,inventorys.date,inventorys.cost
FROM inventorys inventorys
INNER JOIN ( SELECT stock_id, MAX(date) FROM inventorys GROUP BY stock_id ) inv_temp ON inv_temp.date=inventorys.date AND inv_temp.stock_id=inventorys.stock_id
```